# disable Package/Publish Sql tab page

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, publish

Package/Publish Sql tab initially contains warning that this tab should not be used for new development. And once we click 'Enable this page' a UI is shown.

How to disable this or bring back the old warning?

The reason is When deploying to Azure it is not asking DB "remote connection string" when Package/Publish Sql tab is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For providing the connection string during deployment it is not needed to disable package/publish sql tab.As given below "enable the new database publish settings improvements" link will bring back the connection string option. 
[image]